# IntegerType: Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument of type 'T'

Tags: swift, generics, numbers, integer

I have this function that returns an integer within bounds:

```
func randomNumber<T: IntegerType>(min: T, max: T) -> T {
    let n = max - min + 1
    let u = UInt32(n)            // Error: Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument of type 'T'
    let r = arc4random_uniform(u) 
    return r + min
}
```

I dont understand why this is not working because `UInt32` top most protocol is `UnsignedIntegerType`, which conforms to `IntegerType`.

I have to make `n` into `UInt32` because `arc4random_uniform()` takes a `UInt32` as parameter

Why wont this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make at least 2 functions: one for `SignedIntegerType`, one for `UnsignedIntegerType`.

`SignedIntegerType` has type coercing functions: `toIntMax()` and `init(_: IntMax)`

```
protocol _SignedIntegerType : _IntegerType, SignedNumberType {

    /// Represent this number using Swift's widest native signed integer
    /// type.
    func toIntMax() -> IntMax

    /// Convert from Swift's widest signed integer type, trapping on
    /// overflow.
    init(_: IntMax)
}
```

`UnsignedIntegerType` also has type coercing functions: `toUIntMax()` and `init(_: UIntMax)`

```
protocol _UnsignedIntegerType : _IntegerType {

    /// Represent this number using Swift's widest native unsigned
    /// integer type.
    func toUIntMax() -> UIntMax

    /// Convert from Swift's widest unsigned integer type, trapping on
    /// overflow.
    init(_: UIntMax)
}
```

Using these functions, you can:

```
func randomNumber<T: UnsignedIntegerType>(min: T, max: T) -> T {
    let n = max - min + 1
    let u = UInt32(n.toUIntMax())
    let r = arc4random_uniform(u)
    return T(r.toUIntMax()) + min
}

func randomNumber<T: SignedIntegerType>(min: T, max: T) -> T {
    let n = max - min + 1
    let u = UInt32(n.toIntMax())
    let r = arc4random_uniform(u)
    return T(r.toIntMax()) + min
}
```

---

But, we already have handy `numericCast` builtin functions:

```
func numericCast<T : _UnsignedIntegerType, U : _SignedIntegerType>(x: T) -> U
func numericCast<T : _SignedIntegerType, U : _UnsignedIntegerType>(x: T) -> U
func numericCast<T : _UnsignedIntegerType, U : _UnsignedIntegerType>(x: T) -> U
func numericCast<T : _SignedIntegerType, U : _SignedIntegerType>(x: T) -> U
```

`numericCast` can simplify your implementations:

```
func randomNumber<T: UnsignedIntegerType>(min: T, max: T) -> T {
    return min + numericCast(arc4random_uniform(numericCast(max - min + 1)))
}

func randomNumber<T: SignedIntegerType>(min: T, max: T) -> T {
    return min + numericCast(arc4random_uniform(numericCast(max - min + 1)))
}
```

Inner `numericCast` converts `T` to `UInt32`, outer one converts `UInt32` to `T`.

Now, these functions have exact the same implementation codes :) But I think you cannot unify them into one function.

Answer (score 3):

The trouble is that `UInt32` has no `init` that takes an arbitrary `IntegerType`.  Sure, it takes every defined one in the standard library, but what if someone implemented a `UInt128` that conformed to `IntegerType`?  Even if you substituted in `let u = UInt32(n.toIntMax())`, you’ll be stuck when trying to add `r` to `min` since, again, there isn’t an implementation of `+` that will add a `UInt32` to any arbitrary `IntegerType`.  This makes sense given the overflow possibilities – you know `arc4random_uniform(u)` will never return `UInt32` greater than, say, an `Int8.max`, but Swift can’t.  You’d need much richer functionality than `IntegerType` provides to write a truly generic version of this function that had correct pre- and post-conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new Integer Protocol to accept any UInt and also limit UInt64 to UInt32.max to conform to arc4random_uniform limit as follow:

```
protocol Integer  {
    init(_ value:Int)
    var integerValue: Int { get }
}

extension Int     : Integer { var integerValue : Int { return self      } }
extension UInt64  : Integer { var integerValue : Int { return Int(self) } }
extension UInt32  : Integer { var integerValue : Int { return Int(self) } }
extension UInt16  : Integer { var integerValue : Int { return Int(self) } }
extension UInt8   : Integer { var integerValue : Int { return Int(self) } }
extension UInt    : Integer { var integerValue : Int { return Int(self) } }

func randomNumber(min: Integer, max: Integer) -> Int {
    if min.integerValue >= max.integerValue             { return 0 }
    if max.integerValue-min.integerValue+1 > UInt32.max { return 0 }
    return (min.integerValue + arc4random_uniform(UInt32(max.integerValue - min.integerValue + 1))).integerValue
}

randomNumber(UInt(10), UInt64(13))
randomNumber(UInt8(10), UInt32(13))
randomNumber(UInt16(10), UInt16(13))
randomNumber(UInt32(10), UInt8(13))
randomNumber(UInt64(10), UInt(13))
```